# Getting a value back from an array using a random method

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am having issues with getting a correct value from my random method I am using. Everything else in my code works, but when I hit the random message button, I get an output on null null null null null instead of a random value from each array. My code is below. Any help to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
package shoutbox;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;

public class ShoutBox {

    String subj, obj, verB, adJ, adV, cannedM, randomM, tempSubj, tempObj, tempAdj, tempVerb, tempAdverb;

    private final String[] stringItems = {
        "I was sent here by the king to slay you!",
        "I will leave you to your slumber.",
        "I heard you have a piece of treasure I am interested in.",
        "I heard you know a way to save princess Layla from illness.",
        "Might I say you look lovely in the moonight.",
        "I love dragons!",
        "I will slay you and take your treasure!",
        "Are you a luck dragon?",
        "I think I will turn around and go home now.",
        "Go ahead and try to roast me with your fire! I am a wizard, I will prevail!"
    };

    private final String[] subject = {
        "I", "You", "Everyone", "They", "The King", "The Queen", "My Brother",
        "We", "The gold", "The book"
    };

    private final String[] object = {
        "sword", "treasure", "dragon", "cave", "head", "friends", "fire",
        "blood", "jewels", "magic"
    };
    private final String[] verb = {
        "yells", "hits", "torches", "sings", "laughs", "loves", "dances",
        "scouts", "hates", "wants"
    };
    private final String[] adjective = {
        "beautiful", "outragious", "pretty", "scary", "lazy", "heavy", "enormous",
        "hot", "scaly", "scary"
    };
    private final String[] adverb = {
        "quickly", "slowly", "softly", "skillfully", "wickedly", "underground", "tomorrow",
        "uneasily", "quickly", "abruptly"
    };

    public void setSubject(String tempSubj) {
        tempSubj = subj;
    }

    public void setObject(String tempObj) {
        tempObj = obj;
    }

    public void setVerb(String tempVerb) {
        tempVerb = verB;
    }

    public void setAdjective(String tempAdj) {
        tempAdj = adJ;
    }

    public void setAdverb(String tempAdverb) {
        tempAdverb = adV;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        Random genSub = new Random();
        int randomSub = genSub.nextInt(subject.length);
        subj = subject[randomSub];
        return subj;
    }

    public String getObject() {
        Random genOb = new Random();
        int randomOb = genOb.nextInt(object.length);
        obj = object[randomOb];
        return obj;
    }

    public String getVerb() {
        Random genVerb = new Random();
        int randomVerb = genVerb.nextInt(verb.length);
        verB = subject[randomVerb];
        return verB;

    }

    public String getAdjective() {
        Random genAd = new Random();
        int randomAd = genAd.nextInt(adjective.length);
        adJ = adjective[randomAd];
        return adJ;
    }

    public String getAdverb() {
        Random genAdverb = new Random();
        int randomAdverb = genAdverb.nextInt(adverb.length);
        adV = subject[randomAdverb];
        return adV;
    }

    public ShoutBox() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();    //setting up Jframe components
        // Setting width, height, and title of window

        frame.setTitle("Shout Box");
        frame.setSize(450, 400);  // Size of frame window
        frame.setLocation(360, 200);  // Start location of frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);  // So you cannot resize frame

        JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
        JButton randomButton = new JButton("Random Message");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Pick a message and click submit or click random message");

        JList JlistMap;
        JTextArea textArearesult = new JTextArea(2, 21);
        textArearesult.setEditable(false);
        textArearesult.setLineWrap(true);
        textArearesult.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("");
        label1.setForeground(Color.blue);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("         Your Message you have chosen is:         ");
        label2.setForeground(Color.red);
        JlistMap = new JList(stringItems);
        JlistMap.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        JlistMap.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        //add(new JScrollPane(JlistMap));  //Not working as of now
        panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);  // Pink background color

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(JlistMap);
        panel.add(submitButton);
        panel.add(randomButton);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(textArearesult);

        // Action Listener for the submit button to get the message that will display in the JTextArea
        submitButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            textArearesult.setText(ShoutOutCannedMessage()); //using ShoutOutCannedMessage method to return cannedM
        });
        randomButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            textArearesult.setText(ShoutOutRandomMessage()); //using ShoutOutCannedMessage method to return cannedM
        });

        // JList will get the selected Item and set the item to a string value t that will be set to cannedM
        JlistMap.addListSelectionListener((ListSelectionEvent e) -> {
            JList list = (JList) e.getSource();
            String t = list.getSelectedValue().toString();
            cannedM = t;
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);  //set to be visible on panel
    }

    public String ShoutOutCannedMessage() {
        return cannedM;
    }

    public String ShoutOutRandomMessage() {
        randomM = tempSubj + " " + tempObj + " " + tempVerb + " " + tempAdj + " " + tempAdverb + ".";
        return randomM;
    }
}


    package shoutbox;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;

public class ShoutBox {

    String cannedM, randomM, subJ, tempSubj, tempObj, tempAdj, tempVerb, tempAdverb;

    private final String[] stringItems = {
        "I was sent here by the king to slay you!",
        "I will leave you to your slumber.",
        "I heard you have a piece of treasure I am interested in.",
        "I heard you know a way to save princess Layla from illness.",
        "Might I say you look lovely in the moonight.",
        "I love dragons!",
        "I will slay you and take your treasure!",
        "Are you a luck dragon?",
        "I think I will turn around and go home now.",
        "Go ahead and try to roast me with your fire! I am a wizard, I will prevail!"
    };

    private final String[] subject = {
        "I", "You", "Everyone", "They", "The King", "The Queen", "My Brother",
        "We", "The gold", "The book"
    };

    private final String[] object = {
        "sword", "treasure", "dragon", "cave", "head", "friends", "fire",
        "blood", "jewels", "magic"
    };
    private final String[] verb = {
        "yells", "hits", "torches", "sings", "laughs", "loves", "dances",
        "scouts", "hates", "wants"
    };
    private final String[] adjective = {
        "beautiful", "outragious", "pretty", "scary", "lazy", "heavy", "enormous",
        "hot", "scaly", "scary"
    };
    private final String[] adverb = {
        "quickly", "slowly", "softly", "skillfully", "wickedly", "underground", "tomorrow",
        "uneasily", "quickly", "abruptly"
    };

    public void setSubject() {
        Random genSub = new Random();
        int randomSub = genSub.nextInt(subject.length);
        tempSubj = subject[randomSub];
    }

    public void setObject() {
        Random genOb = new Random();
        int randomOb = genOb.nextInt(object.length);
        tempObj = object[randomOb];
    }

    public void setVerb() {
        Random genVerb = new Random();
        int randomVerb = genVerb.nextInt(verb.length);
        tempVerb = verb[randomVerb];
    }

    public void setAdjective() {
        Random genAd = new Random();
        int randomAd = genAd.nextInt(adjective.length);
        tempAdj = adjective[randomAd];
    }

    public void setAdverb() {
        Random genAdverb = new Random();
        int randomAdverb = genAdverb.nextInt(adverb.length);
        tempAdverb = subject[randomAdverb];
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return tempSubj;
    }

    public String getObject() {
        return tempObj;
    }

    public String getVerb() {
        return tempVerb;    
    }

    public String getAdjective() {
        return tempAdj;
    }

    public String getAdverb() {
        return tempAdverb;
    }

    public ShoutBox() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();    //setting up Jframe components
        // Setting width, height, and title of window

        frame.setTitle("Shout Box");
        frame.setSize(450, 400);  // Size of frame window
        frame.setLocation(360, 200);  // Start location of frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);  // So you cannot resize frame

        JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
        JButton randomButton = new JButton("Random Message");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Pick a message and click submit or click random message");

        JList JlistMap;
        JTextArea textArearesult = new JTextArea(1, 30);
        textArearesult.setEditable(false);
        textArearesult.setLineWrap(true);
        textArearesult.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("");
        label1.setForeground(Color.blue);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("         Your Message you have chosen is:         ");
        label2.setForeground(Color.red);
        JlistMap = new JList(stringItems);
        JlistMap.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        JlistMap.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        //add(new JScrollPane(JlistMap));  //Not working as of now
        panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);  // Pink background color

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(JlistMap);
        panel.add(submitButton);
        panel.add(randomButton);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(textArearesult);

        // Action Listener for the submit button to get the message that will display in the JTextArea
        submitButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            textArearesult.setText(ShoutOutCannedMessage()); //using ShoutOutCannedMessage method to return cannedM
        });
        randomButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            textArearesult.setText(ShoutOutRandomMessage()); //using ShoutOutCannedMessage method to return cannedM
        });

        // JList will get the selected Item and set the item to a string value t that will be set to cannedM
        JlistMap.addListSelectionListener((ListSelectionEvent e) -> {
            JList list = (JList) e.getSource();
            String t = list.getSelectedValue().toString();
            cannedM = t;
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);  //set to be visible on panel
    }

    public String ShoutOutCannedMessage() {
        return cannedM;
    }

    public String ShoutOutRandomMessage() {
        randomM = getSubject() + " " + getObject() + " " + getVerb() + " " + getAdjective() + " " + getAdverb() + ".";
        return randomM;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have reworked a lot of the methods and I am still getting the same errors. I have researched the issue, but nothing I have tried thus far has worked. Do you have any further feedback for me, to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the values of your attributes `tempSubj`, `tempObj`, `tempVerb`, `tempAdj`and `tempAdverb`.

Notice that you've declare these attributes but you haven't affect them with any value. Therefore, they assume the value `null`.

In order to fix this, you have set them with some value explicitly or invoke their setters, which you've already created. Also you've to fix your setters because they're not properly setting your attributes:

```
public void setSubject(String subj) {
    tempSubj = subj;
}

public void setObject(String obj) {
    tempObj = obj;
}

public void setVerb(String verb) {
    tempVerb = verb;
}

public void setAdjective(String adj) {
    tempAdj = adj;
}

public void setAdverb(String adv) {
    tempAdverb = adv;
}
```

**EDIT**

Other approach, is to use your getters, where you have the random code logic:

```
public String ShoutOutRandomMessage() {
    randomM = getSubject() + " " + getObject() + " " + getVerb() + " " + getAdjective() + " " + getAdverb() + ".";
    return randomM;
}
```

Comment: Note that the setters are broken, they set the input parameter, not the (hidden) member variable.

Comment: Thank you all, let me take another look and see if I can figure this out. I have used setters and getters before, but not in this context, so I need more research it seems. I thought it had something to to with them. I appreciate the comments.